# how to auto generate number value in a textbox using c# and the number starts from 2001 in textbox?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int billno=2000;
    string code;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        billno = Convert.ToInt32(code);
        billno = billno + 1;
        textBox1.Text = " "+ billno;

    }
```

Comment: Please give more detail to better understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please don't just throw code at us, give us a clear example of what you want and what you have tried already and we'll be able to help you more effectively

Comment: Help me friends! how to generate number automatically in a bill no textbox?

Comment: Number should increment sequentially  like 2001,2002,2003.... or you wand random number?

Comment: number should increase sequentially like 2001, 2002, 2003

Comment: Help me jams! number should increase sequentially like 2001, 2002, 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int billno=2000;
    string code;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        billno = billno + 1;
        textBox1.Text = billno.ToString();

    }
```

Here `billno` will increment by 1 on every Form load event.